# loop in 'savefig' and 'title' in a plot for several files

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, matplotlib, plot

I have several files .txt and I create a loop for reading this and plot each file in a different plot, the reading is fine, my problem is for the loop in the fuction 'savefig' and in the 'title' of the plot because these just save the last file. my code is this:

```
enter code here

frames = np.linspace(10,49,40)

filelist = []

for i in frames:
    filelist.append("xyz_%s.txt" %i)

plotlist = []

for i in frames:
    plotlist.append("proy_%s.png" %i)

timelist = []

for i in frames:
    timelist.append("TIME = %s [Myr]" %i)

plt.rcParams.update({'figure.max_open_warning': 0})

for fname in filelist:
    data = np.loadtxt(fname)
    x = data[:,0]
    y = data[:,1]
    z = data[:,2]

fig = plt.figure()

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 3) 
gs.update(left=0.07, right=0.98, bottom=0.3, top=0.6, wspace=0.3)

ax0 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
line0, = ax0.plot(x,y,'r.')

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[1], sharey = ax0)
line1, = ax1.plot(x,z,'b.')


ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[2], sharey = ax0)
line2, = ax2.plot(y,z,'g.')

plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator())

ax0.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(3))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(3))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(3))

ax0.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(3))
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(3))
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(3))

ax0.set_xlabel('x[pc]', size=10)
ax0.set_ylabel('y[pc]', size=10)
ax1.set_xlabel('x[pc]', size=10)
ax1.set_ylabel('z[pc]', size=10)
ax2.set_xlabel('y[pc]', size=10)
ax2.set_ylabel('z[pc]', size=10)

ax0.set_xlim(-15,15)
ax0.set_ylim(-15,15)
ax1.set_xlim(-15,15)
ax1.set_ylim(-15,15)
ax2.set_xlim(-15,15)
ax2.set_ylim(-15,15)

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

for ftime in timelist:
    ax0.set_title(r'$ftime$',fontsize=12,horizontalalignment='left',verticalalignment='bottom')

for fplot in plotlist:
    plt.savefig('fplot',facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), transparent=True) 
    plt.cla()
    plt.clf()
    plt.close()
```

Ps: I have problems to read the files like xyz_02.0txt because the 'linspace' don't star with zero, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, `plt.savefig('fplot',facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), transparent=True)` always overwrites the file named `fplot`. You need to change it in the for loop.

To answer your Ps question, use `zfill` to do zero paddings. For example,

```
filelist.append("xyz_" + str(int(i)).zfill(2) + ".txt")
```

Comment: many thank for the Ps answer. 
I'm still new in python, you know how to change the loop-for to iterate in the title of the plot and also save every figures?

Comment: `for i in frames:`
    `filelist.append("xyz_" + str(int(i)).zfill(2) + ".txt")`
`print(filelist)`

Comment: Thanks, yes I did that and works.
But I don't know how to iterate the out of the plot I want n plots with names like proy_01.png,proy_02.png, ...proy_23.png, ...proy_n.png

Comment: It can be done similarly. For example, you have `plt.savefig(filename,facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), transparent=True)` and `filename` is a str. Make a `for` loop to iterate `i` over a range of numbers, and do `filename = "proy_" + str(int(i)).zfill(2) + ".txt".`

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get filenames like "xyz_10.txt", "xyz_11.txt", and so on through "xyz_49.txt", then the same sort of thing with "proy_10.png", etc., then you don't necessarily need a Numpy array.  A standard Python list will do the trick.  `Just set frames = range(10,50)`.  Or:

```
frames = range(10,50)
filelist = [ "xyz_%s.txt" % str(i) for i in frames ]
plotlist = [ "proy_%s.png" % str(i) for i in frames ]
```

If you want your `frames` list to be the strings "01", "02", and so on through "40", then you could use the `.zfill` command to pad the single-digit numbers with an extra 0:

```
frames = [ str(i).zfill(2) for i in range(1,41) ] # This is ["01", "02", ... "40"]
filelist = [ "xyz_%s.txt" % c for c in frames ] # We don't need str(c) here; c is already a string
plotlist = [ "proy_%s.png" % c for c in frames ]
```